# Как сочетанием клавиш, отобразить рабочий стол?

Tags: windows-8

Имеется `Windows 8.1` имеется программируемая клавиатура `Crown` которая имеет доп плавиши, на которые можно повесить разные функции, в том числе и сочетания клавиш.

При клике правой мышкой на панели задач есть меню, `Показать рабочий стол`, по сути функция `Свернуть все окна`, в том числе и те что в полноэкранном режиме.

Можно ли средствами OS (без программирования) забиндить данную функцию на клавиатуру?

Answer (score 0):

Можно. Есть две комбинации клавиш <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> и <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>